# Is there any way to create a Google Calendar import function within a Google Gadget running in Calendar?

Tags: import, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-gadget

I spent some time looking for this, but I am not sure even the Google API includes a function for importing an ICS file into a calendar. Basically, I want to create a Google Gadget that is embedded in my Google Calendar and allows me to import ICS files from within it, without having to go through the built-in import functionality. The reason why I want this is because I want to be able to control the import and use ICS files as templates. I will give you an example:

I create a study schedule in google calendar and export it to my harddrive as an ICS file.

If I used Google's built-in import function, I can import it easily in a calendar I set up for my new student, HOWEVER, the calendar will import with starting dates that used to be when I created the template. So if it is 2015 now, but I created the template in 2012, the ICS events will import in the new calendar in the year 2012.

I want to have my own Google Gadget on the side that allows me to import the ICS, but then also runs a script that can move all the imported events with a start date of "today". I already have experimented with such a Google Script running through Google Sheets and moving events in a calendar. I just want to make it easier and more user friendly as an import Google Gadget.

Is there any way to create something like this? Can you point me to the correct functions in the API and the google gadgets manual that may help? Do you know of any scripts already out there that can do this?